# Is it possible to check if the pasted text in SWT text has special characters through key listener?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a SWT Text which should accept only characters which fall in this range : [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9].
For this i have added a KeyListener on the Text and below is the code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
{
    String enteredCharacterInStr = String.valueOf(event.character);
    boolean isAlphaNumeric = pattern.matcher(enteredCharacterInStr).find();

    if(event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT ||
        event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT ||
        event.keyCode == SWT.BS || 
        event.keyCode == SWT.DEL )
    {
        event.doit = true;
    }
    else if(isAlphaNumeric)
    {
        event.doit = true;
    }
    else if(event.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && (event.keyCode == 'a' ||
                                            event.keyCode == 'c' ||
                                            event.keyCode == 'v' ||
                                            event.keyCode == 'x' ) )
    {
        event.doit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        event.doit = false;
    }

}
```

The above code will work from user not entering Special characters, but fails when user copies a text containing Special characters and pastes in the Text.

Is it possible to achieve this through KeyListener?

Comment: Would you like to filter out the special characters or stop the pasted text from inserting if it contains a special character?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [VerifyListener](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FVerifyListener.html), this example only allows numbers from 1-8:

```
    text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent event) {
            char[] charArray = event.text.toCharArray();
            for (char testChar : charArray) {
                if (testChar <= '0' || testChar >= '9') {
                    event.doit = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And this example filters out all special characters:

```
    text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent event) {
            event.text = event.text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
        }
    });
```